# Ajax going to [object%20Object]

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to do a simple request like this:

```
    $('.asd').change(
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1/folder/index.php/controller/action/integer',
                success: function(data){}
            });
        }
    );
```

This code tries to go to http://127.0.0.1/folder/index.php/controller/[object%20Object] instead and gets a 404. Where is it pulling the object from? I'm using a simple string.

Comment: whats your content type? where is your data. is this your complete ajax request? paste full code of `$.ajax`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%5Bobject%20Object%5D (404 not found) when attempting to submit via AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357445/5bobject20object5d-404-not-found-when-attempting-to-submit-via-ajax)

Answer (score 20):

For me the issue was that I was using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`.

```
// fails:
$.post({
    url: "/example/" + this.id,
    // ...
});

// works:
$.ajax({
    url: "/example/" + this.id,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't set type to 'POST' this is a http GET

Comment: I just had a problem where using `$.ajax({type: 'POST'...}})` was actually using GET - very strange. I moved to using `$.post()`, and made the same syntax mistake as you did above. For `$.post()`, the first parameter is the URL string, followed by an object - which is slightly different than the syntax for the shorthand version `$.ajax()`. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

`ajax` expects a parameter map.
`post` expects single parameters:

```
// fails:
$.post({
    url: "/example/" + this.id,
    // ...
});

// works:
$.post("/example/" + this.id);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and dug all over looking for an answer. Unfortunately, this contributor never came back with one. Mine was a stupid error. upon returning from Ajax, I used inadvertently named my variable after a reserved word. Here is what I had:

```
$.post('/MyApp.php', { param: 'getLocation' },
  function(xml) {
    location=$(xml).find('Location');
  }
});
```

Coded like this, upon return from Ajax the page is redirected to http://myurl/[Object%20object] which makes perfect sense now.

Resolution: change the "location=$..." to "clocation=$..."
Hopefully this answer will help someone else. It's a tough one to debug.

Comment: Not relevant here: the user hasn't defined any variables. Entirely your fault for using global variables.

Comment: A little harsh considering Dave was just putting something out there on a relatively old question. My problem was the improper construction of the URL. That's the OP's problem too, probably through a redirect or he has inadvertently left something out of his code sample.

Answer (score 2):

For me, working in Play and using jsRoutes this was very very painful to figure out.

It seems that Play (javaScript) will do an Ajax GET without issue using the following syntax:

```
$.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.ajax(inurlparam))
.done(function(data) {
  }).fail(function(data) {
  })
```

However (and here is the nasty part)... If you wish to do a POST you need to use the `absolutURL()` method on the URL first to get the ajax (or post) not to include an `[object%20Object]` into the url at post time. No amount of debugging the url or the form params seemed to indicate what was happening nor why. I just literally "guessed" this solution out of sheer frustration. PS: Note the brackets on the end of `absolutURL()` -- js people will instantly get those mean "do" the function not just pass me the handle to it.

```
  var url = jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.ajaxPost(inurlparam).absoluteURL();
  var formData = $('#form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData
  }).done(function(data) {
  }).fail(function(data) {
  })
```

I'm answering this here as this is where Google lead me once I finally realized it might not be my coding that was causing the problem :)

Comment: I just got bit by this once more and I'm so glad I remember documenting it :)

Answer (score 0):

You Must Desriallize the text to Number(Int):

```
var ID = parseInt( 
$(this)
  .closest("tr") //tr of DataTable 
  .find("td") //td of ....
  .eq(0)
  .text(),
10 
);
```

Comment: this item can parse item to int from text with this article https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp