# %5Bobject%20Object%5D (404 not found) when attempting to submit via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to pass variables via ajax to a PHP script that will run a MySQL query. However, I keep getting the error 404 Not Found with:  "http://myurl/database/%5Bobject%20Object%5D".

It looks like it's trying to send the data to http://myurl/database/%5Bobject%20Object%5D instead of the PHP script I've defined. Really at a loss on this one... I thought putting the absolute URL in would work.

Below is my code. Would be eternally grateful for any help....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertData()
 {
    var dataid= $('#dataid').attr('value');
    var industry = $('#industry').attr('value');
   var geolocation = $('#geolocation').attr('value');
    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myURL/database/InsertData.php",
        data: "dataid="+ dataid+"&amp;industry="+ industry +"&amp;geolocation="+ geolocation,
        });
return false;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

Comment: @RobW - it is irrelevant

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As andi said, [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) expects an URL string as a first parameter; if you want to pass an option object, you must use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

When you try to call `$.post(<option object>)`, the option object is used as an URL; in that process, it is cast to a string (and an object cast to a string becomes `[object <type>]` in Javascript; in this case, `[object Object]`), it gets URL-encoded (`%5Bobject%20Object%5D`), and, since it does not start with a `/` or a protocol name, it is interpreted as a relative URL and gets prefixed with the current protocol, domain and path. Then, since there are no more parameters, an empty POST AJAX request is sent to that URL.

Another problem is that you use `&amp;` to separate the parameters; that should be done only in HTML, here you should just use `&`. (Or a data object, as Evan said, that way you don't need do think about encoding issues.) And `.val()` and `.attr('value')` are not the same; the first is the current value of the field, the second is whatever value it had when the page was loaded.

The simplest way to this correctly is this:

```
function insertData() {
    var data = $('#dataid,#industry,#geolocation').serialize();
    $.post('http://myURL/database/InsertData.php', data);
    return false;
}
```

This assumes that the three fields have the same `name` and `id` as [$.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) uses `name` for the parameter name.

Comment: Alright, but it was supposed to work as per the docs: `jQuery.post( [settings ] )` *A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. All properties except for* `url` *are optional*. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 9):

You should change the `$.post` to `$.ajax` or pass the URL and data as parameters.
[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is just a shorthand to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and it takes the URL as the first paramter.

So it should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myURL/database/InsertData.php",
    data: "dataid="+ dataid+"&amp;industry="+ industry +"&amp;geolocation="+ geolocation
});
```

or, with $.post

```
$.post("http://myURL/database/InsertData.php", "dataid="+ dataid+"&amp;industry="+ industry +"&amp;geolocation="+ geolocation);
```

Remember that the docs are almost always helpful

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Not getting the 404 error anymore. One more question if you have time: I'm trying to pass PHP variables to the JavaScript function above like this:  var data = $("#<?php echo $DataSQLResult[id]?>dataid,#<?php echo $DataSQLResult[id]?>industry,#<?php echo $DataSQLResult[id]?>geolocation').serialize();
    $.post('/database/InsertData.php', data); but it doesn't seem to work... How do I pass a PHP variable to a javascript function when it's using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

try sending your data in an object instead, like:

```
data: {
    dataid : dataid,
    industry : industry,
    geolocation : geolocation
}
```

Comment: If the problem was with the data parameter, the URL would not get corrupted.

Comment: a malformed string can corrupt the URL no?

Comment: No. In the first place, this is a POST request, so the data does not get anywhere near the URL; and even if it would, you would get something like `http://myURL/database/InsertData.php?<corrupted part>`, the end of the URL would not magically disappear.

Comment: That said, the string *is* malformed; you can use a string as data for the POST request, but you should not htmlencode the `&` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Evan is right, tryy sending your data an an object, jquery will take care of properly URL encoding the values. String concatenations can be problematic in js.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a jquery bug. `jQuery.post` is a shorthand of `jQuery.ajax({method:"post"});`, so I changed my code to this, and it worked for me. Hope they will correct this issue.

Note, the issue still exists in 1.10.2 and 2.0.2 versions.