# JSON Request appended with [object%20Object] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, getjson

I'm trying to fetch a custom JSON feed I have written with jQuery using the `getJSON` method.  For an unknown reason the URL seems to be having `cache_gen.php?location=PL4` stripped from the end and replaced with [object%20Object] resulting in a 404 error occurring.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
var fetchData = function() {

    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {

        var api_location = "http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php";
        var user_location = "PL4";
        var date = new Date();

        console.log(api_location + '?location=' + user_location);

        jQuery.getJSON({
            type: "GET",
            url: api_location + '?location=' + user_location,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                console.log(jsonData);
            }
        });

    } else {
        alert('Your browser is not yet supported.  Please upgrade to either Google Chrome or Safari.');
    }
}

fetchData();
```

From the console log I can see the URL string is calculated correctly as: `http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php?location=PL4`

However the second line in the console is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

**UPDATE 19/01/2013 23:15**

Well, I've just converted so that is fits the docs perfectly using `$.ajax`.  I've also added a fail event and logged all of the data that gets passed to it.

```
var fetchData = function() {

    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {

        var api_location = "http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php";
        var user_location = "PL4";
        var date = new Date();

        var url = api_location + '?location=' + user_location;

        console.log(url);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: api_location + '?location=' + user_location,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jsonData) {

                console.log(jsonData);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus );
                console.log('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown );
                console.log('jqXHR' + jqXHR);
            }
        });

    } else {
        alert('Your browser is not yet supported.  Please upgrade to either Google Chrome or Safari.');
    }
}

fetchData();
```

After this my console gives me the following information:

```
http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php?location=PL4
download_api.js:44textStatus: parsererror
download_api.js:45errorThrown: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
download_api.js:46jqXHR[object Object]
```

I have ensured the headers for the JSON feed are current, and the feed is definitely serving valid JSON (it effectively caches a 3rd party service feed to save costs on the API).

Comment: http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php?location=PL4 is not a working url. <----- click it

Comment: @popnoodles, it may be a `/etc/hosts` redirection :). But, certainly `.dev` sounds fishy

Comment: .dev is a development domain.  It have set this up has an Apache virtual-host on my local system, which is has an entry in my ```/etc/hosts``` to ensure that is resolves properly. I can access this domain in my browser, its the same domain as where the JS file is being loaded from.

Comment: What appears on screen when you just browse to the URL?

Comment: @Alexander i did consider hosts after I posted but thought it's so unlikely

Comment: Just as it should I get the JSON data. http://cloud.danielgroves.net/Q0Wr

Comment: I can assure you that your feed is not serving valid JSON and that is what is causing the error that you are now seeing.

Comment: I can prove it, copy your response from dev tools and paste it in http://jsonlint.com/ - it will show you where your error is.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. I appreciate this. It seems to be appending a random ```2728``` onto the end of the file during the ```readfile()``` method.

Comment: Solved. Thanks @Adam.  If you you want the rep make an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%5Bobject%20Object%5D (404 not found) when attempting to submit via AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357445/5bobject20object5d-404-not-found-when-attempting-to-submit-via-ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you see this error:

```
http://weatherapp.dev/cache_gen.php?location=PL4
download_api.js:44textStatus: parsererror
download_api.js:45errorThrown: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
download_api.js:46jqXHR[object Object]
```

Is because your JSON is invalid. Even if a response comes back from the server correctly, if your dataType is 'json' and the returned response is not properly formatted JSON, jQuery will execute the error function parameter.

http://jsonlint.com is a really quick and easy way to verify the validity of your JSON string.

Comment: Extending @Adam's good answer. More generally, something is mismatched between your 'datatype' value on the call (explicit or implied) and the actual data returned from the server. I was specifying "html" as my datatype and got this error. I omitted the optional datatype parameter and stopped seeing the error. I'm definitely returning html and inserting in the page but am willing to bow down to the ajax goddess and let her think my return value is any type she wants as long as my call works.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue today. In my case I was assigning a JSON object to a variable named 'location' which is a reserved word in [JavaScript under Windows](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) and appearantly is a shorthand for windows.location! So the browser redirected to the current URL with [object%20Object] appended to it. Simple use a variable name other than 'location' if the same thing happens to you. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This saved me some time & headache. I was not aware that "location" was a reserved word in JavaScript on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the actual function usage:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You can't pass on object parameter into `$.getJSON` like with `$.ajax`, your code should look like this:

```
    jQuery.getJSON('api_location + '?location=' + user_location)
         .done(function() {
            //success here
         })
         .fail(function() {
           //fail here
         });
```

To maybe make it a little clearer, `$.getJSON` is just a "wrapper function" that eventually calls `$.ajax` with `{type:'get',dataType:'JSON'}`. You can see this in the link I provided above.

Comment: Actually just easier for the OP to replace .getJSON with .ajax

Comment: @popnoodles why? OP not using any options that `$.getJSON` doesn't already include

Comment: @charlietfl because they've written their code as if they should have been using .ajax - changing just 7 characters is easier.

Comment: Just updated the main post, what you picked yup on was a mistake after trying multiple different things.  Added more debugging information now as well.