# Play 2 javascript routing with https

Tags: nginx, https, playframework-2.0

I'm using play's javascript routing (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting). I have a nginx front-end server, which I configured to force https. 
When I try to make an ajax call, I get an error, since the javascript routing generates http urls and my browser blocks them because of cross origin access.

How can I configure the javascript routing to serve https urls?

Comment: I'm hitting a slightly similar problem right now -- unsure how/why the system gets tricked into presenting the wrong style of URL but it does and it is non-obvious as to why. As this has just taken a fledgling production server off line when it worked flawlessly in development I guess I'm currently learning the true value of staging :)

Answer (score 1):

How are you making the calls?  The Play JavaScript router returns objects with two properties, one is a `method` property which contains the method, eg `POST`, `GET` etc.  The other is a `url` property which contains the relative URL.

There are also two methods on the returned object, one called `absoluteURL`, the other called `webSocketURL`.  These will return absolute URLs according the hostname of the current page, and they will be http or https (or ws or wss) based on whether the current page is secure or not.

So, if using with jQuery for example, you should be able to just:

```
$.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.myAction("foo")).then(...)
```

And it will use the relative URL, or you can also:

```
var route = jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.myAction("foo")
$.ajax({
  method: route.method,
  url: route.url,
  ...
}).then(...)
```

Comment: yes, that's how i do it. problem is: i'm serving https through nginx, but my jsRoutes generates http urls. so `jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.myAction("foo").url` is `http://myserver.url/myaction/:foo` instead of `https://...`. can i configure my jsRoutes to only serve https?

Comment: The url parameter returns a relative url. Only the absoluteURL method adds the scheme and host, and it adds that based on the current page, if its https it will return an https url. What makes you think it's returning an http URL? Do you have some example code that shows the problem?

Comment: no, it doesn't and that's my problem. my site url is `https://account.xxx.xxx/i/4#/overview`, the produced javascript routes are [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qQ9y/), which gives me an error on ajax request: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://account.xxx.xxx/i/stmtids/4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://account.xxx.xxx' is therefore not allowed access.`. So I don't know why my javascript routing generates `http` urls, when I'm on an `https` site.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. Maybe you're thinking of Call? https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L346-L372 take the RequestHeader into account. AFAICT https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/routing/JavascriptReverseRouter.scala#L37-L58 do not.

Comment: Ah - Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37550189/2162886 as absoluteURL is a FIX for another issue with jsRoutes versus Ajax and when used in that context it (for me also) is returning HTTP routes on an HTTPS server (behind a load balancer that IS handling traffic as HTTPS at all times).

Good that we can call absoluteUrl(true) but would be nice if we had the protocalRelativeUrl option built in...

Comment: To be clear(er) -- `jsRoute.MyController.someRoute()` appears to work fine and pulls up the correct HTTPS or HTTP as needed. However `jsRoute.MyController.someRoute.absoluteUrl()` does not. (Again in MY environment which might mean nothing to anyone else... It is however a clue that something is different and I'll dig through code to find out what next.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make that requests using absolute urls, Hostnames, protocols and ports should match because of same-origin policy. You have at least two options:

1. Use relative urls on ajax requests like `href="/your/page"`
2. Use the protocol relative url's. Example: `href="//your.domain.com/your/page`.

Here is a detailed article by Paul Irish about protocol relative url's:

http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: the routes are generated from playframework's javascript routing. that's my problem. (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as a parameter to `absoluteURL`/`websocketURL`.

Frome Chrome dev tools:

```
> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().absoluteURL
  function (s){return _s('http',s)+'localhost:9000'+r.url}

> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().absoluteURL()
  "http://localhost:9000/events"

> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().absoluteURL(true)
  "https://localhost:9000/events"

> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().webSocketURL
  function (s){return _s('ws',s)+'localhost:9000'+r.url}

> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().webSocketURL()
  "ws://localhost:9000/events"

> jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarController.getEvents().webSocketURL(true)
  "wss://localhost:9000/events"
```

`_s` is defined at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/routing/JavascriptReverseRouter.scala#L54 as

```
function(p,s){return p+((s===true||(s&&s.secure))?'s':'')+'://'}
```